# The resource type 'locations/operationResults' could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices' for api version '2023-08-01-preview'

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-language-understanding, azure-openai, azure-ai

I'm trying to deploy a finetuned model in Azure Machine Learning Studio and I got this error:

Failed to create deployment
InvalidResourceType: The resource type 'locations/operationResults' could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices' for api version '2023-08-01-preview'. The supported api-versions are '2016-02-01-preview,2017-04-18,2021-04-30,2021-10-01,2022-03-01,2022-10-01,2022-12-01,2023-05-01,2023-06-01-preview,2023-10-01-preview'.

Any idea?

(this StackOverflow question ["The resource type 'locks' could not be found in the namespace 'Microsoft.Authorization' for api version '2020-05-01'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72028634/9258504) is similar, but not the same error)